# How to can I read ony two tags of this xml if I have 200 files like this in a folder by python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, dom

**I want to write only `<TradingDate>` and `<Product>` in csv file.**

```
      <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
        <EmissionSpotMarketECarbixResults>
            <Status>
                <Commodity>Emission Spot ECarbix</Commodity>
                <TradingDate>2018-03-14</TradingDate>
                <CreationTimestamp>2018-03-14T20:08:43+01:00</CreationTimestamp>
            </Status>
            <Results>
                <Product>
                    <Index>Day</Index>
                    <Unit>EUR/tCO2</Unit>
                    <IndexPrice>11,250</IndexPrice>
                    <Volume>3632000</Volume>
                </Product>
            </Results>
        </EmissionSpotMarketECarbixResults>


import os
from os import walk
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

for filenames in walk("D:\EEX_EMS\XML"):
    (filenames)
    fname= list(filenames)
    for f in fname[2]:
     if "EmissionSpotMarketECarbixResults" in f :
      tree = ET.fromstring(f)
```

Comment: Can you post any code you have so far so we know exactly what you need help with? Do you need to know how to walk through the directories to find the files, or how to find the specific elements, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

With 'xmlstarlet', you can come one step nearer the final result:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c //Commodity -n -c //Product -n data.xml


<Commodity>Emission Spot ECarbix</Commodity>
<Product>
                    <Index>Day</Index>
                    <Unit>EUR/tCO2</Unit>
                    <IndexPrice>11,250</IndexPrice>
                    <Volume>3632000</Volume>
                </Product>
```

If you know the fields come in exactly this order, you can use -v instead of -c. Otherwise you will have to pick them out individually.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve it. The data you have mentioned is stored in a "data.xml" file and the updated xml is stored in "data_update.xml".

Have look and let me know if it works for you.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def main():
    # Read
    tree = ET.parse('data.xml')

    #read and update TradingDate
    trading_element = tree.find('*/TradingDate')
    trading_element.text = "2011-07-09"

    product_element = tree.find('*/Product')

    for elem in product_element.iter():
        if elem.tag == 'Index':
            elem.text = "Month"

        if elem.tag == 'Unit':
            elem.text = "%"

        if elem.tag == 'IndexPrice':
            elem.text = "12,13"

        if elem.tag == 'Volume':
            elem.text = "4000"

    #save in another file
    tree.write("data_update.xml")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```